# Is it possible to make the "Save" button in React admin Sticky in React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I am using reactadmin , i need to make the save button in edit page sticky as the form is too long , but the save button is by default inside the form.Is it possible to make the save buttong sticky to the bottom of the page

```
const StickyEditToolbar: React.FC<StickyEditToolbarProps> = ({ size = 'medium', ...props }) => {
  // overriding default styles of react admin toolbar
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    toolbar: {
      position: 'sticky',
      bottom: '20px',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  });

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Toolbar {...props} alwaysEnableSaveButton classes={classes}>
      <SaveButton
        redirect={false}
        submitOnEnter={false}
        className={clsx(size === 'medium' && 'w-48', size === 'large' && 'w-56', size === 'small' && 'w-36')}
      />
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

export default StickyEditToolbar;

 <Edit {...props} >
    <SimpleForm redirect={false}  toolbar={<StickyEditToolbar />}>
      <TextField label='Email' source='user.email' />
      <TextField label='First name' source='user.firstName' />
      <TextField label='Last name' source='user.lastName' />
   ........
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can inject a custom toolbar using `<SimpleForm toolbar>`, and use the `sx` prop to manipulate style. Due to the way the `position:sticky` CSS rule applies, you must also reset the overflow of the containing element.

```
 <Edit {...props} sx={{ "& .MuiPaper-root": { overflow: "visible" } }}>
    <SimpleForm
      redirect={false}
      toolbar={<Toolbar sx={{ position: "sticky", bottom: 0, zIndex: 2 }} />}
    >
      <TextField label='Email' source='user.email' />
      <TextField label='First name' source='user.firstName' />
      <TextField label='Last name' source='user.lastName' />
   ........
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
```

Test it live at https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-rain-j23g2e?file=/src/posts/PostEdit.tsx

Comment: Tried something similar to that , but was getting error when i use sx:   Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<EditProps & { children: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>; }, "resource" | ... 16 more ... | "basePath"> & Pick<...> & Pick<...>'.ts(2322).Im using version "react-admin": "^3.19.0",

Comment: The solution I gave you is for react-admin 4.x. For version 3, you'll have to use material-ui's makeStyles.

Comment: working now ,thanks